# Why does Xcode say that my iPhone app is only able to run on iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad

I have a project in Xcode with two targets. One target is for the iPhone only and the other is for iPad only.

The iPad target works as expected, but the iPhone target does not.

If I try to run it in the simulator, it starts the iPad simulator every time, but in iPhone compatibility mode with the 2x button.

If I try to run in on my iPhone 4 device, I get this message:

> Can’t install application. The application at /Users/jacob/Documents/code/Projects/TVGuide/build/Debug-iphoneos/TVGuidePlus.app can only be installed on iPads.

This is Xcode 3.2.6 and the iOS 4.3 SDK.

I have `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY` defined at the target level and it looks like it is set correctly. The problem is the same for debug/release/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it turned out that I had Armv7 selected as architecture for my iPhone build. After changing that to armv6, I can now install and run the build on my device.

Answer (score 0):

have you selected the simulator as iphone?
most iphone apps are supposed to work on ipad too.
otherwise you may need to go to the project tab and go to project settings. there are some setting involving the choice of ios. i have not tried this since i havent recieved the error but i hope that it works.

Comment: I can select the iphone in the simulator and it will run, but the next time I "run" the application from XCode it will start the iPad simulator again.

Comment: yes that happens for me too. it dosent really matter since most iphone apps can run on ipad and vice versa. the only difference is that the ipad simulator takes a little longer while to load after youve clicked build and go.